# Modifying a substring using C#

Tags: c#, substring

If I have a string like **SMITH 9-2 #3-10H13** how can I modify the 9-2 to be 09-02 using C#?  Another example is RODGER 3-1 #5-11H17 would be RODGER 03-01 #5-11H17.  Another is GWIN 10-3 #6-11H12 would be GWIN 10-03 #6-11H12.  and so on..  I'm stumped.

Comment: What have you tried? Which bit in particular are you having difficulty with?

Comment: Are you talking about replacing specific instances of strings, or any numerals in the string before the '#' should be two-digit, zero-padded?

Comment: @JamesMichaelHare-  Yes thats correct.  Sorry I didn't word my question correctly

Comment: @Greg-  I can use the .IndexOf method of the string to get to the first '-' but I'm trying to understand how I check for the number values on either side of the '-' and pad them with zeros if they are less than a 10 digit number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not the prettiest code but here you go

```
        String text = "SMITH 9-2 #3-10H13";

        String[] values = text.Split(' ');

        String v = values[1];

        String[] numbers = v.Split('-');

        String newValue = numbers[0].PadLeft(2, '0') + '-' + numbers[1].PadLeft(2, '0');

        String newText = text.Replace(" " + values[1] + " ", " " + newValue + " ");
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a way to do it using `Split` and `Join`:

```
string str = "SMITH 9-2 #3-10H13";
string[] parts = str.Split(' ');
string[] numbers = parts[1].Split('-');
parts[1] = string.Join("-", numbers.Select(x => x.PadLeft(2, '0')));
string result = string.Join(" ", parts);
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably the most failsafe way:

Construct a regex to match the portion of your string in question. The use the match to run a replace on the string.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with Regex can you explain

Comment: Yes, Regular Expressions, it is a somewhat universal way of representing string formats. .NET has an entire library for its regex engine. System.Text.RegularExpresssions. Take some time to learn how to use them as you will need them pretty often in your career.

Answer (score 2):

Going off your comment above. If you can parse the string to get the substring with the numbers then you would simply use `.PadLeft(2,  '0'))` to pad the numbers so that there length was always 2.

Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92h5dc07.aspx for more info.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a basic solution that uses regular expressions. It is probably not as robust as it could be but it should be enough to get you started.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Normalize("SMITH 9-2 #3-10H13"));
        Console.WriteLine(Normalize("RODGER 3-1 #5-11H17"));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static string Normalize(string input)
    {
        const string pattern = @"([a-zA-Z]+)\s+(\d{1,2})-(\d{1,2})\s+(#\d-\d{2}[A-Z]\d{2})";
        var regex = new Regex(pattern);
        var match = regex.Match(input);
        return match.Groups[1].Value + " " +
            match.Groups[2].Value.PadLeft(2, '0') + "-" +
            match.Groups[3].Value.PadLeft(2, '0') + " " +
            match.Groups[4].Value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a regular expression to search for the number pattern:

```
Regex myRegex = new Regex(" [0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2} ");
```

This should pick up two one- or two-digit numerals separated by a dash and with spaces on either side.  Then you can parse it, prepend zeroes if necessary, and add it back into the string:

```
string search = "SMITH 9-2 #3-10H13";
string myMatch = myRegex.Match(search).Value;
string[] numberArray = myMatch.Split('-'); //grab the two numbers as separate strings
if (numberArray.Length == 2)
{
    int num1 = Int32.Parse(numberArray[0]);
    int num2 = Int32.Parse(numberArray[1]);
    string str1 = (num1 < 10 ? "0" + num1.ToString() : num1.ToString());
    string str2 = (num2 < 10 ? "0" + num2.ToString() : num2.ToString());
    string result = " " + str1 + "-" + str2 + " ";
    search = search.Replace(myMatch, result);
}
else
{
    throw new Exception("Bad result!"); //sanity check, so you know if it goes wrong
}
```

You can use this concept to process your strings one by one.  It's probably a good idea to put some more error handling in there, and test it on a representative selection of your inputs.  For example, I'm assuming that both elements in my string array produced by `myMatch.Split('-')` will be valid integers that `Int32.Parse()` will like.  And the exception-throwing will of course have to go away or be handled better.

Comment: Also, another way to do zero padding (this is just fyi - not a critique) is this: num1.ToString("00")

Comment: @Dracorat - No, it'll only match the 9-2 because of the spaces in front and back.  Try it in a regex tester.  http://www.regexlib.com/RETester.aspx

Comment: You're right - I just somehow didn't see the spaces in the pattern. I don't need the tester I just need better eyes =)

Comment: Ha.  Easy to do.  Our eyes see what they expect sometimes, instead of what's actually there.  Thus the need for code reviews!  :-)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can split the information by using a space, then split element one on a dash, then reformat the integers accordingly.

Crude way:

```
  string test = "SMITH 9-2 #3-10H13";
  string[] items = test.Split(new char[] { ' ' });
  string[] nums = items[1].Split(new char[] { '-' });
  nums[0] = string.Format("{0:00}", Convert.ToInt32(nums[0]));
  nums[1] = string.Format("{0:00}", Convert.ToInt32(nums[1]));
  items[1] = nums[0] + "-" + nums[1];
  string result = string.Join(" ", items.ToArray());
```

Comment: sorry I was posting to Jonathan and my response ended up here

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

Mark Peters is right. The problem is not as easily solved with Regex.Replace as I first thought. The updated code below should work for all cases though:

```
var input = new List<string> {
                "SMITH 9-2 #3-10H13",
                "RODGER 3-1 #5-11H17",
                "GWIN 10-3 #6-11H12"
                };

Regex r = new Regex(@"(?<=(\s|-))(\d{1,2})(?=(-|\s))", RegexOptions.None);

foreach(var inp in input) {
      var s = r.Replace(inp, match => match.Value.PadLeft(2, '0'));
      Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

**Update 2**
Also see Mark Peters' answer which uses a much simpler regular expression with a different overload of `Regex.Replace`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Regex varient that uses the overload of Regex.Replace() to pass in a delegate to do the replacement text:

```
static void Main()     
{    
    Console.WriteLine(
    Regex.Replace("SMITH 9-2 #3-10H13", @"(\w+\s+)(\d+)-(\d+)", 
    m=> m.Groups[1].Value + 
        m.Groups[2].Value.PadLeft(2,'0') + "-" +
        m.Groups[3].Value.PadLeft(2,'0')
        ));
}
```

[EDIT]
or even simpler: This replaces the first two numbers with padded versions:

```
static void Main()     
{    
    Console.WriteLine(new Regex(@"\d+").Replace("SMITH 9-2 #3-10H13",
    m=> m.Value.PadLeft(2,'0'),2));
}
```